# Limiting choices to an Generic Inline FK field dependant on the object that the Inline is being related to

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to limit the choices of a FK field found in a generic inline, depending on what the inline is attached to.

For example I have `Article`, with a Generic relation `Publishing`, edited inline with the `Article`.

I'd like for the PublishingInline to 'know', somehow, that it is currently being edited inline to an Article, and limit the available PublishingTypes to `content_type` `Article`.

This is the start that I've made:

```
class PublishingInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            data = kwargs.pop("data", {})
            if kwargs["instance"]:
                publishing_type_kwargs = {
                    'content_type': kwargs["instance"].content_type, }
                data["publishing_type"] = PublishingType.objects.filter(**publishing_type_kwargs)
                kwargs["data"] = data
        except KeyError:
            pass

        super(PublishingInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class PublishingInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):

    form = PublishingInlineForm

    model = get_model('publishing', 'publishing')
    extra = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) on your `GenericInlineModelAdmin` is your friend.

Something along these lines should do it:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    print self.parent_model # should give you the model the inline is attached to
    if db_field.name == "publishing_type":
        kwargs["queryset"] = ... # here you can filter the selectable publishing types based on your parent model
    return super(PublishingInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```